# Grails list is replaced by index, so what is the default?

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I created a new grails application using grails 2.3.7 and I removed the `index` action from the controller.
My controller has `static scaffold = true`
So now when I try to access `applicationname/controller/index` I get the list of objects which was shown by the `list` action in earlier versions of grails.

It has become confusing now, How do I redirect my `applicationname/controller/` to some other action, because now I cannot do the following -

```
def index() {
redirect(action: someotheraction)
}
```

Comment: The `list` action has been replaced by `index` in order to by more REST compliant. I am not sure if I understand your question. If you want to redirect from one to another controller you have to implement an controller action yourself by using `redirect(action:'someOtherAction')`. Or what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a value to the defaultAction property. See http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/defaultAction.html.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following to keep the url same as applicationname/controller/ but still forward request to a different action

```
def index() {
forward(action: someotheraction)
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that "index" is now a scaffold for list, i do not want to loose that.